# Team foundation server 2010 slow after 3-4 mins idle

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, vpn

I installed a TFS server 2010 and I'm connecting to it via VPN. The first time I execute some kind of command towards the TFS it is slow (10-20 secs to respond). After that it is as fast as hell. If I leave it like this (not doing any compares, get latest, view history and etc. (just coding to an already checkout file)) after 3-4 mins it is slow the first time again. Is it some kind of seeting that it drops the connection after some time has passed? I've set the idle time-out of IIS application pool to 999 (minutes)

. It didnt help. Thank you in advance.

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: It wont let me connect to TFS server when i set those settings. When i remove them I connect properly.

Comment: I guess the problem could be in the VPN. Im using team viewer

Comment: Just in case the syntax has changes between 2008 and 2010, here's an updated post describing the tracing for 2010: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292973/How-to-Troubleshoot-TFS-Build-Server-Failure

Comment: Okey I generated the Log file.

Comment: Okey I found the time difference (about 20 secs). Here is a screenshot

http://postimage.org/image/v06kjph8f/full/

Comment: Changed the VPN from TeamViewer to Hamachi and it works like a charm.